# Can you patent something illegal?

Tags: thc

This patent is for a device to smoke Hash Oil, currently a schedule one narcotic in the USA. There is no other use for this product. Can it be patented?

Comment: You will need to tell us the patent number for us to address a specific patent or application. In general, something that is illegal **can** be patented.

Comment: "schedule one narcotic" are only illegal if you don't have a license -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_Substances_Act